# Direct (TCP) connections to/between Azure web apps?

Tags: azure, tcp, azure-web-app-service

We are building a large application that will consist of several components - which we'd like to deploy as web apps in Azure (probably written in Go). Web apps seem to be a good fit for our needs as they're easy to set up, we'll need to scale each component separately and it seems fairly straightforward to integrate them with a Git repository.

There will be a large number of messages exchanged between these apps and speed is critical so we'd like to create direct TCP connections between them. Is this possible at all? I've tried writing and deploying a simple class that listens to TCP requests but I've been unable to reach it from my own machine (I'm getting "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host." when trying to connect to it via TCP).

Is this possible or is there perhaps another easy way to create extremely fast connections to/between Azure web apps? Maybe there's another (preferably simple) solution?

I'm new to the Azure infrastructure so I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious. Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be possible, since outbound IP might change per below open suggestion.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/6722199-dedicated-reserved-outbound-ip-address

How about use WebSocket for your messaging? Azure App Service supports WebSocket as well as [Go](https://github.com/shrimpy/gowebsockettry)

Comment: Websockets seems like exactly what we need - and something we hadn't considered. I got a hello world example working pretty quickly on Azure. Thank you!